# column width for text without space

Tags: tables, width

how is it possible to control the column width in a table having a very long text without space.

```
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{l p{2cm}}
    datapath & /home/username/path/to/directory/very/long
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

`p{2cm}` only works if the second column element was something like `/home/ username/ path/ to/ directory /very /long`. Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: use hyperref or url package then `\url{/home/username/path/to/directory/very/long}` to allow url to linebreak

Comment: yes this works but I just did not want them to appear as hyperlink.

Comment: Do you only want it to break on / or wherever the 2cm boundary falls?

Comment: url package doesn't make it a link (hyoerref does by default, or you could turn that off probably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrow the idea from David but use `\path` instead (since it is a path)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{l p{2cm}}
    datapath & \path{/home/username/path/to/directory/very/long}
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]